# Problema com AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou desenvolvendo um site em ASP.NET MVC, queria que quando mudasse de tela só fosse atualizado minha div `.ESTRUTURA` eis o código:

Javascript:

```
function loadPage(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: page,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log($('.ESTRUTURA').html(data));
            $('.ESTRUTURA').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML (No caso é o proprio _Layout.cshtml)

```
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        @Html.Partial("_Header")
        <div class="ESTRUTURA"> 
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_Footer")
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/vendors/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/vendors/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Dentro da minha DIV `.ESTRUTURA` tem o `@RenderBody()`, acredito que o problema esteja ai. A variavel `data`, recebe o HTML inteiro da pagina (porém não deveria).

Comment: Então o teu problema esta na construção da variável `data`. Tens de rever o que estás a receber no teu pedido ajax

Comment: A variavel recebe o retorno do @RenderBody(), consegui arrumar esse problema mudando o retorno das Controllers para PartialView(), porém a primeira pagina que carrego (Home), tem que ser View(), senão não aparece os outros conteudos da pagina como Header Footer e navbar

Comment: Exacto, o teu Home tem de ser uma View. No entanto estou a perceber qual é o teu problema... A variável `data` receber o retorno do RenderBody??

Comment: Sim, que no caso quando eu coloco PartialView(), o RenderBody() só e retorna conteudo, porém quando coloco View() ele me retorna a pagina inteira, preciso que ele só execute o View() da Home a primeira vez, as outras precisam ser como PartialView()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim, podendo funcionar de duas formas.

A primeira é fazendo com que as `action` retornem apenas a `partial view`, isto é, a `view` sem a master page (_Layout.cshtml).

***Controller*** (Primeira forma)

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction() {
   return PartialView();
}
```

Mas também temos um problema, caso o usuário decida acessar a URL diretamente só irá retornar a parte partial, nesse caso eu trabalharia da forma abaixo.

***Controller*** (Segunda forma)

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction() {
   return View();
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("MinhaAction")]
public ActionResult MinhaActionPartial() {
  return PartialView();
}
```

E você deve alterar no sei jquery o método request para `POST` em vez de `GET`, assim fará com que toda requisição `POST` retorne a parte partial e `GET` a página inteira.

***Jquery***

```
function loadPage(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: page,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log($('.ESTRUTURA').html(data));
            $('.ESTRUTURA').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, Diego, funcionou perfeitamente.